# bootstrap reorder elements in same column on page resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.0 and Angularjs and ran into an issue I am not sure there is a clean solution for.

I have a page with 3 blocks, 2 of which are in the same column, and I am trying to find a way to split the two into the the top and bottom of the third when I resize to mobile.  So from this:

```
BBAA
BBCC
```

to this:

```
AA
BB
BB
CC
```

I know this could probably be done with CSS, but I am trying to avoid that if at all possible.  I am hoping I am just missing something or combination of things already in Bootstrap that will let me do this.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What about using col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-*

This two thing as the order suggest push and pull columns To rigth or left

Here are a good article about it

http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/

Sorry that i have not time right now for a fiddle